# Will the play store not allow you upload an Android app if the package name is similar to someone else already on the play store?

Tags: android, google-play

What are the restrictions on package names when uploading an Android app to the Google Play store?

Will the play store not allow you upload an Android app if the package name is similar to someone else already on the play store? Do you really need to own the domain name that you use in your package? What is stopping me from using a package name for a domain name that someone else owns? Just wondering how that whole process works.

EDIT: If you made a cool app and are trying to publish it to the play store, will it block you/prevent you from publishing it if the package name matches someone else out there? If so, I guess that would mean you need to rename your package in your Android app right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Package name it is app id in market. So it is NOT possible to publish app which has same id with any existing app.

Comment: Cool. Is the same true for iOS and their market place?

Comment: I don't know about iOs. Ask a separate question)

Comment: iOS is the same I believe

Comment: But the play store has no idea whether or not you actually own that domain name though, right? So if you own a domain name but haven't yet uploaded an app to Google Play, couldn't someone else just have used the reverse of your domain name and had an app up there before you? And you could do nothing about it?

Comment: @MicroR if someone published app once, to update it you need to have release keystore and credentials of user who has published it. So, only with this data you able to update apk file.